# How to get an object from a MongoDB nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection for storing chat objects with messages embedded as a nested array. The entire collection looks like this:

```js
chats = [
  {
    _id: 0,
    messages: [
      {
        _id: 0,
        text: 'First message'
      },
      {
        _id: 1,
        text: 'Second message'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    messages: []
  }
]
```

I would like to update a single message and return it to the user. I can update the message like this (in Node):

```js
const chat = chats.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: ObjectId(chatID),
        "messages._id": ObjectId(messageID)
    }, {
        $set: {
            "messages.$.text": newText
        }
    });
```

The issue is that this query updates a message and returns a **chat** object, meaning that I have to look for an updated message in my code again. (i.e. `chat.messages.find(message => message._id === messageID)`).

Is there a way to get a **message** object from MongoDB directly? It would also be nice to do the update in the same query.

**EDIT: I am using Node with mongodb.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MongoDB methods `findOneAndUpdate`, `findAndModify` do not allow to get the updated document from array field,

- projection will return updated sub document of array using positional `$` after array field name
- `returnNewDocument: true` will return updated(new) document but this will return whole document object

**The problem is, MongoDB cannot allowing to use a positional projection and return the new document together**

For temporary solution
try using [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#projection), this will return original document from array field using `$` positional,

```js
const chat = chats.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: ObjectId(chatID),
    "messages._id": ObjectId(messageID)
  }, 
  { $set: { "messages.$.text": newText } },
  { 
    projection: { "messages.$": 1 }
  }
);
```

Result:

```js
{
    "_id" : 0.0,
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0.0,
            "text" : "Original Message"
        }
    ]
}
```

To get an updated document, a new query could be made like this:

```js
const message = chats.findOne({
    _id: ObjectId(chatID),
    "messages._id": ObjectId(messageID)
  }, {
    projection: {'messages.$': 1},
}).messages[0];
```

Result:

```js
{
    "_id": 0.0,
    "text": "New message",
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Here's the result I got: `{lastErrorObject: { n: 1, updatedExisting: true }, value: { _id: 5f350aa109650a062003cda7, messages: [ [Object] ] }, ok: 1}`

Comment: removed property `returnNewDocument` check updated answer check now, where you extincting this  query? nodejs, mongoose, mongodb, driver?

Comment: Same result. I'm using Node with mongodb.

Comment: Yes, the `new` property seems to work. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219986/discussion-between-mikhail-stefantsev-and-turivishal).